# Why RegExp not matching?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm using Node v.0.8.8.

In the following example, why **url** isn't being matched with `/([\w-]+)` regular expression? Is it a bug or am I doing something incorrect?

```
var patterns = [
    '/([\w-]+)',
    '/.*'
],
    url = '/asdf';

for (var pattern in patterns) {
    var re, match;

    re = new RegExp('^' + patterns[pattern] + '$');

    if ((match = re.exec(url))) {
        console.log(url + ' matched: ' + patterns[pattern])

        // break the loop since we've already found the first match
        return false;
    }
    else{
        console.log(url + ' NOT matched: ' + patterns[pattern])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you create the regex from string literal, you need to escape the backslash:

```
'/([\\w-]+)'
```

Comment: Damn. Didn't know that! Thank you very much! Will accept in 10 minutes.